# C++ partially filling array using null

Tags: c++, arrays, null

NoobQuestion:
I heard that filling a char array can be terminated early with the null char. How is this done? 
I've searched every single google result out there but still have come up empty handed.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is way to vague to answer. (Why would  _filling_ be terminated early depending on something read in the array to fill?) You might want to improve that question. For now I voted to close it.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean something like this:

```
    char test[11] = "helloworld";
std::cout << test << std::endl;
test[2] = 0;
std::cout << test;
```

This outputs

```
helloworld
he
```

?

Comment: +1, @user481407: also note that the size is the size of helloworld+1 because of null-terminated string.

Answer (score 1):

That's a convention called "null-terminated string". If you have a block of memory which you treat as a char buffer and there's a null character within that buffer then the null-terminated string is whatever is contained starting with the beginning of the buffer and up to and including the null character.

```
const int bufferLength = 256;
char buffer[bufferLength] = "somestring"; //10 character plus a null character put by the compiler - total 11 characters
```

here the compiler will place a null character after the "somestring" (it does so even if you don't ask to). So even though the buffer is of length 256 all the functions that work with null-terminated strings (like `strlen()`) will not read beyond the null character at position 10.

That is the "early termination" - whatever data is in the buffer beyond the null character it is ignored by ***any code designed to work with null-terminated strings***. The last part is important - code could easily ignore the null character and then no "termination" would happen on null character.